# Return the correct length of a object in React's state after filtering it

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-state

I am new to React and been developing this feature where there's a filter option where the user types on an input the name or e-mail of the users he's looking for, and the list is updated as the input changes.

When the component loads, `useEffect` hook fetchs data from my api and set the return into my state, and the data typed inside the filter input is also saved in state.

My filtering when typing works perfectly, the `filter` alongside `map` works perfectly and list only the users I'm looking for.

My issue here is that when the component loads, it also show how many users were found, right now I'm only listing the array length when the component mounts, so my question is:

how can I also updated the size of the `users` array length without breaking my state? If I set the filtered array in my state, and after erasing the query string, my state will be broke... I tried to create another state with the filtered result but did not work, there's another better approach or am i doing something wrong?

`<ContentSearchReturn section="Mentores" qtdUsers={users.length} />`

[image]

`Mentors` component which renders the page and `ListMentors` is the components which renders my each Evee box.

```
const Mentors = () => {
  const formRef = useRef(null);
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      const { data } = await api.get("/colaborador/mentores");

      setUsers(data);
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Layout>
      <BodyContent
        header="Gerenciamento de Mentores"
        breadcrumb="Home > Mentores"
      >
        <Form ref={formRef} style={{ marginBottom: "3vh" }}>
          <Row>
            <Col lg="8" style={{ backgroundColor: "" }}>
              <FormGroup>
                <Input
                  label="Informe o nome ou e-mail do mentor"
                  name="pesquisa"
                  testid="fieldPesquisarColaborador"
                  style={{ marginTop: "0", marginBottom: "0" }}
                  onChange={(e) => setFilter(e.target.value)}
                />
              </FormGroup>
            </Col>

            <Col lg={{ size: 3, offset: 1 }} style={{ backgroundColor: "" }}>
              <Button
                text="Cadastrar"
                onClick={() => history.push("/admin/create-collaborator")}
                style={{ width: "100%" }}
              />
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
        <ListMentors users={users} filter={filter} />
      </BodyContent>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Mentors;
```

`ListMentors` component and `qtdUsers` is the prop that shows the 7 results on the print above.

```
const ListMentors = ({ users, filter }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <ContentSearchReturn section="Mentores" qtdUsers={users.length} />
      <Row>
        {users.length > 0 ? (
          users
            .filter((user) => {
              if (!filter) return true;
              if (user.nome.includes(filter) || user.email.includes(filter)) {
                return true;
              }
            })
            .map((user, index) => {
              return (
                <UserBox
                  key={index}
                  nome={user.nome}
                  cargo={user.nome_cargo}
                  departamento={user.nome_departamento}
                />
              );
            })
        ) : (
          <div>
            <h1>Ops! 0 resultados...</h1>
          </div>
        )}
      </Row>
    </>
  );
};

export default ListMentors;
```

Thank you so much for your time and sorry for my english, not native speaker here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `useMemo` to store the filtered array of users.

Then `filteredUser.length` will always be the size of the filtered array (or the entire array when `!filter` is `true`)

Note that the derived value will only be computed when `users` or `filter` change.

```js
const ListMentors = ({users, filter}) => {
    const filteredUsers = useMemo(() => {
        return users.filter((user) => {
            if (!filter) return true;
            if (user.nome.includes(filter) || user.email.includes(filter)) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }, [users, filter]);

    return (
        <>
            <ContentSearchReturn section="Mentores" qtdUsers={filteredUsers.length} />
            <Row>
                {filteredUsers.length > 0 ? (
                    filteredUsers.map((user, index) => {
                        return (
                            <UserBox
                                key={index}
                                nome={user.nome}
                                cargo={user.nome_cargo}
                                departamento={user.nome_departamento}
                            />
                        );
                    })
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <h1>Ops! 0 resultados...</h1>
                    </div>
                )}
            </Row>
        </>
    );
};

export default ListMentors;
```

PS.

```js
const filteredUsers = users.filter((user) => {
    if (!filter) return true;
    if (user.nome.includes(filter) || user.email.includes(filter)) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

without using `useMemo` should work fine as well, but it will cause you to recompute the filtered array on every render.

Comment: Thank you so much! Solved my problem very well! I'll dig into useMemo right now!! Thanks again =)